# chrome://tracing displaying more lanes than process_names in timeline.json

Tags: google-chrome, tensorflow, profiling, chromium

So far, I have assumed that the number of lanes displayed by the Chrome [Trace Event Profiling Tool](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool) `chrome://tracing` always matches the number of `process_name`s defined in a loaded file like `timeline.json`. This is for timelines that were recorded in `TensorFlow` and exported to the file with `timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format()`.

I now face a situation where `timeline.json` contains 3 `process_name`s like this:

```
{
    "name": "process_name",
    "args": { "name": "Allocators" },
    "ph": "M", "pid": 0
},
{
    "name": "process_name",
    "args": { "name": "/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 Compute" },
    "ph": "M", "pid": 1
},
{
    "name": "process_name",
    "args": { "name": "/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 Tensors" },
    "ph": "M", "pid": 2
},
```

whereas the tool displays 4 lanes like that:

[image]

And in the file the single operation `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape_1` in lane 3 does not reference `"pid": 3` but `"pid": 1`.

Is this mismatch a feature (i.e. am I misunderstanding things) or a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of lanes is basically just the highest level of parallelism that occurred during the run. There are usually many tens of threads (using defaults in Eigen library) used for kernel executions. Instead of showing all of them (many completely empty), tensorflow packs node executions into as fewer lanes as possible. Here is the [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/48c54eee17b35ebc15e274e36632eccb76072f7d/tensorflow/python/client/timeline.py#L399) that does it.

You can also [see](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/48c54eee17b35ebc15e274e36632eccb76072f7d/tensorflow/python/client/timeline.py#L469) that `pids` are fake.